# Missing files while Exporting and importing a Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have created a Maven (normal) project in Eclipse.  Now I want to export it.  I exported it to .jar archive.  But just for testing, if I am importing the same back to Eclipse, then the actual source files are missing.  :-)  What is the actual process to export Maven project to a .jar archive with the original source files so that I can import it back somewhere else (e.g., Eclipse) and have access to the source files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To Export project you should use `Export.. / General / Archive File` wizard.

Then you could use `Import... / General / Archive File` wizard to import it back.

If you need a jar, you should use Maven launch configuration, with goals like `package` and [source:jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html) (to generate Maven source archive).

Answer (score 0):

While exporting as a .jar, select the checkbox `Export Java source files and resources`.